# How to get ipython console in spyder to print the full text?

Tags: python, printing, parameters, classification, random-forest

Can anyone help me out?
I have run a random forest classifier through a pipeline, and want to print the parameters used with the classifier using `.get_params`.
However when it prints to the ipython console the information I need is truncated by '...'

```
('RandomForestClassifier', GridSearchCV(cv=2, error_score='raise',
       estimator=RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class...   pre_dispatch='2*n_jobs', refit=True, return_train_score='warn',
       scoring=None, verbose=0))])>
```

Does anyone know how to print this in full? 
I've used `np.setprintoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)`. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Spyder has a bug where set_printoptions is ignored. If it works from the command line, but not Spyder, wait for release 3.3.3.

https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/7885